# Combinations with Entries Unique in Row and Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, unique, combinations

Using Python 3, I need to return a list of possible combinations of matrix items where no item in the combination shares a row or column with any other matrix item in the combination.

For example,
    [[A,B,C],
     [D,E,F],
     [G,H,I]]

returns:
A,E,I
A,F,H
B,D,I
B,F,G
C,E,G
C,D,H

I can not seem to figure out an efficient way to do this.

I was hoping that this could be achieved without say, producing ALL combinations and then testing if the items within each combination satisfies the unique row and column rule.

If anyone has any pointers whatsoever, that would be awesome.

Comment: as in your example, can you guarantee non-repeating elements?

Comment: @ShawnMehan no, I can not.

Answer (score 2):

I'd attack this with a recursive routine.

```
If only one element in matrix, return it.
Else
  for each element in first row
    choose the element (call it E)
    call self with that row & column deleted from matrix (list comprehension)
    for each sequence in returned list:
      prepend E to the sequence.

return the list of sequences
```

Python implementation:

```
def traverse(mat):
    # Identify matrix traversals: one element from each row & col.
    # Input:
    #   mat -- square matrix (list of lists)
    # Return:
    #   list of all element combinations that satisfy the requirement

    if len(mat) <= 1:
        return mat

    result = []
    for elim, head in enumerate(mat[0]):
        submat = [row[:elim] + row[elim+1:] for row in mat[1:]]
        print(submat)
        subcombo = traverse(submat)
        for row in subcombo:
            result.append([head] + row)

        print(result)

    return result


mat = [['A', 'B', 'C'],  ['D', 'E', 'F'],  ['G', 'H', 'I']]
print(traverse(mat))
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'E', 'I'], ['A', 'F', 'H'], ['B', 'D', 'I'], ['B', 'F', 'G'], ['C', 'D', 'H'], ['C', 'E', 'G']]
```

This can be reduced greatly with in-line manipulation and list comprehensions, but I wanted to keep the solution more available for other languages.

Comment: Thank you!  My mind was telling me to use a method involving only parts of the other rows but was unsure if there is a better option.

Comment: One question though, how will this provide more than a single result?  I.e. AEI and AFH not just AEI?  Or am I not seeing it...

Comment: You return a list.  For instance, the 'A' choice recurs on submatrix [[E, F], [H, I]] and gets back the list [[E, I], [F, H]].  The last step at this level is to prefix A onto each list to get [[A, E, I], [A, F, H]].  That completes the 'A' choice, and the loop repeats with the 'B' and 'C' choices.  The main program receives a list of all 3! allowable permutations.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you! Will comment back with results.

Comment: Can you share how you implemented?

Answer (score 1):

```
def combMatrix(m):

        # index each letter with row and colum
        ll = [[ (y, x.index(y),l.index(x)) for y in x] for x in m]

        # flatten list
        flattened = [val for sublist in ll  for val in sublist]

        # no need for deepcopy, it just me first time using it
        from copy import deepcopy
        lst2 = deepcopy(flattened)

        lall = []
        temp = []
        srowt = set()
        scolt = set()
        pospath = []

        # loop from one copy of the list over the other indexed list of tuples
        for el in lst2:

            row = el[1]
            col = el[2]
            for t in flattened:
                rowt = t[1]
                colt = t[2]

                # if row index and column index are different
                if row != rowt and col != colt:
                    # and if for this tuple row index and column index is not in the visisited
                    # append that tuple, it is a good candidate
                    if rowt not in srowt and  colt not in scolt:
                        temp.append(t[0])
                        srowt.add(rowt)
                        scolt.add(colt)
                    else:
                        # here we append onother candidate to a list of possible path
                        pospath.append(t[0])


            temp.append(el[0])
            temp = sorted(temp)
            pospath.append(el[0])
            pospath = sorted(pospath)

            if temp not in lall:
                lall.append(temp)
            if pospath not in lall:
                lall.append(pospath)

            temp = []
            srowt = set()
            scolt = set()
            pospath = []



        for c, el in enumerate(lall):
            print(" {} {}".format(c, el))


l = [['A','B','C'],
     ['D','E','F'],
     ['G','H','I']]

combMatrix(l)
```

**OUTPUT**

0 ['A', 'E', 'I']

1 ['A', 'F', 'H']

2 ['B', 'D', 'I']

3 ['B', 'F', 'G']

4 ['C', 'D', 'H']

5 ['C', 'E', 'G']